# Android passing an arraylist back to parent activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've been searching for a simple example of this with no luck.

In my android application I have two activities:
1. The main activity which is launched at startup
2. A second activity which is launched by pressing a button on the main activty.

When the second activity is finished (by pressing a button) I want it to send back an ArrayList of type MyObject to the main activity and close itself, which the main activity can then do whatever with it. How would I go about achieving this? I have been trying a few things but it is crashing my application when I start the second activity.

When the user presses button to launch second activity:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

The array which is bundled back after pressing a button on the second activity:

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putParcelableArrayList("myarraylist", mylist);
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
```

And finally a listener on the main activity (although I'm not sure of 100% when this code launches...)

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        final ArrayList<MyObject> mylist = extras.getParcelableArrayList("myarraylist");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mylist.get(0).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? The onActivityResult() seems to be crashing my application.

EDIT: Class with parcelable methods:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Plan implements Parcelable{
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public Plan(){
    }

    public Plan createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Plan plan = new Plan();
        plan.setId(in.readString());
        plan.setName(in.readString());
        return plan;
}

    public Plan(String name, String id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Plan ID: " + id + " Plan Name: " + name;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Plan> CREATOR
    = new Parcelable.Creator<Plan>() {
        public Plan createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Plan();
        }

        @Override
        public Plan[] newArray(int size) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new Plan[size];
        }

    };

}
```

After the second activity finished, onactivityresult is called, but nothing displays inside the toast, its blank. any ideas? I'm guessing my class is still messed up...

EDIT: got it to work

I had the method that Peter supplied in the wrong place. It should be inside creator, like this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Plan> CREATOR
= new Parcelable.Creator<Plan>() {
    public Plan createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Plan plan = new Plan();
        plan.setId(in.readString());
        plan.setName(in.readString());
        return plan;
}
```

and not out on its own.

Many thanks to Peter! Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: could you please provide some Logcat output? Also, you say that *starting* the second activity crashes your app. Could there be another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `MyObject` must implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) in order to be serialized/deserialized by Android when put inside Bundle.

**Update:**

The method name is `createFromParcel`. And actually you have to create your object Plan from data in the parcel:

```
public Plan createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Plan plan = new Plan();
        plan.setId(in.readString());
        plan.setName(in.readString());
        return plan;
}
```

Comment: It does implement parcelable. although I had to put 2 empty methods at the bottom of the class to get it to work:  @Override
 public int describeContents() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

Comment: That is the problem: you have to actually IMPLEMENT something in those methods. They get called when system needs to create a serialized form of your MyObjects.

Comment: What am I supposed to implement inside them?

Comment: Your class must also have a static field called CREATOR. Look at the simple example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: In `writeToParcel()` you must write all data inside your MyObject to a Parcel. In CREATOR you must be able to instantiate your MyObject from Parcel.

Comment: added class and logcat to main post peter. tried to implement what you said, still crashing

Comment: Also, you are getting NullPointerException in your login.java in line 51. Post code if you need help.

Comment: login = secondactivity, I just modified the names for better clarification in the main post :P

Comment: @peter I got it to stop crashing peter. I had a rogue variable in the code getting some data which doesnt exist. Regardless, the app doesnt seem to do anything now. The onactivityresult() doesnt seem to be called. any ideas? I added your method to my code. Gonna clean up the main post with the class now.